# FFMPEG and RPi picamera mp4 video recording

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture a `.mp4` video using RPi + picamera and ffmpeg
but I can't do this with this command

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f lavfi -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-1.mp4



 pi@raspberrypi:~ $ raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f lavfi -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-1.mp4
ffmpeg version N-77945-gd6b3062 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
  libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
  libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 25.100 /  6. 25.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
[NULL @ 0x1f1b580] Requested output format 'lavfi' is not a suitable output format
recording-1.mp4: Invalid argument
```

if I'm trying to do the same for `.flv` video it works fine

```
raspivid -t 50000 -fps 25 -b 500000 -vf -o - | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv -r 25 -t 50000 -pix_fmt yuv420p recording-3.flv
```

I don't understand where my mistake is, can some one help?

Comment: What is the output of `ffmpeg -formats`?

Answer (score 1):

lavfi (Libavfilter input virtual device) is an INPUT format.  Here you have it as an output format.

https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#lavfi

FLV (Flash Video) IS an output format.  That's why the second one works for you.